# Stop loaded audio after second click

Tags: javascript

I have loaded some audio in upon the click of a image. That works fine, the only problem now is getting it to stop when they click the image again. Here's the code. Of course it doesn't work. Any help would be nice.

```
var sound = new Audio("plane.mp3");
    sound.preload = 'auto';
    sound.load();


    function planeNoise() {
      var click=sound.cloneNode();
      click.play();
        if(click>1){
            sound.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event handler should work for you. the following just an example, don't know how your code is organized.

```
$('.image').one("click", function(){
    planeNoise();
});


function planeNoise() {
   var click=sound.cloneNode();
   click.play();
}
```